# Change color of serpentine line in VS

Tags: visual-studio

I want to change my theme from light to dark in VS 2012. Problem, the serpentine line is by default blue and you cannot see it in front of a dark background. 
Since I wanna see my spelling (and other) errors imediately I am looking for the option to change this color but cannot find it anywhere. Anyone who knows where to change this?

Comment: Did you install an additional VS extension to check spelling errors?

Comment: No. I just installed some themes. But it is the same with all the themes, the serpentine line is blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to TOOLS - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors - (Settings for Text Editor) - Compiler Error - select Item foreground for a more visible color.